# Swagger UI / Editor like page - add to my web site

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I've created YAML file (and JSON file respectively) manually via [swagger editor](http://swagger.io/swagger-editor/).

Now I want to embed the cool auto generated page from the swagger-editor tool into my website, so users could read and test it (via 'Try this operation' button) my API live.

I don't want swagger to generate any code for me and I don't need it to update the documentation (YAML or whatever) automatically. I will update my static YAML/JSON file whenever I'll need - manually.
Does swagger support this kind of feature? Is it something related to the 'Generate Client' in the swagger editor toolbar?
I'm looking for some html/js/css files that could load static YAML file and generate something similar to the right page of swagger-editor. 
BTW, I'm using Apache web server (not that important).

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I'm looking for client side only - some js/css/html that could add the above requirements, I don't mind to generate it again from time to time (whenever I'll change my YAML file / my REST API)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well,
I found the tool I was looking for, it's the [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui).
It's not looking exactly as the swagger-editor right side UI but it satisfy my requirements - it parse my JSON file (which I wrote manually as YAML) in client side online with only static files (no server side work, only serve the pages).

Thanks anyway!

EDIT: I found that more people are interested in the editor view solution in the following [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/664)

EDIT2:
I've add a short dirty workaround for previewing only the relevant section of the swagger-editor. You can see the changes [here](https://github.com/itayB/swagger-editor/commit/c9bb68bd366c075a9dea7aedd1926f619bbe9614).
You can try it:

1. clone [my forked](https://github.com/itayB/swagger-editor) repo: `git clone http://github.com/itayB/swagger-editor.git`
2. `cd swagger-editor`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm start`

**EDIT3: (2022)**

1. clone [swagger-editor](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor) repo.
2. In `index.html` (root folder) add:

   ```
      .topbar, .Resizer, .Pane1 {
        display: none;
      }
   ```
3. In `index.html` (root folder) modify:

   ```
      .Pane2 {
        width: 100% !important;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
   ```
4. In `index.html` (root folder) modify `SwaggerEditorBundle` to include:

   ```
       SwaggerEditorBundle({
         ...
         url: 'doc/swagger.json',
         ...
       })
   ```

where `doc/swagger.json` is the path to your spec file.

Please note: This preview shows the output of the file spec-files/default.yaml.
I've only made some view changes, all the editor logic is still running behind.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I am trying to do the same thing and was thinking swagger-ui was the tool I was looking for.

Comment: @andymal yes, just follow their instructions in github.. (only first step needed) - clone the project, use the 'dist' directory and copy there your json file. You might need to edit index.html file with the path of the json file if you put it in a different place..

Comment: Up and running within 20 minutes. What a cool project! All I had to do was point index.html to my generated json file and it's up and running. Nice!

Comment: @andymal Congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

I think You're looking for swagger-server (https://github.com/BigstickCarpet/swagger-server).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it and update if it's what I was looking for, but from first look - it's require node.js and cannot handle the YAML parsing in client side..